# How install multiple version of perl

Tags: windows, perl, version

I have the following question in perl.
**1)** Is it possible to install multiple version of perl(example perl version: 5.6 and perl version 5.24) in windows system.

**2)** In case if the above question 1 is possible then how to call the perl file using version. For example, call the new version perl file from old version of perl file.

Answer (score 4):

**On Windows systems**

You can use [`berrybrew`](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew)

To get a list of available versions:

```
berrybrew available
```

Based on available versions you can install with following command:

```
berrybrew install 5.10.1_32
```

To switch the version:

```
berrybrew switch 5.10.1_32
```

---

**On unixy systems**

Using [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/), you can install different versions of Perl.

You can run a single command against a specific version of Perl using the following command:

```sh
perlbrew exec 5.27.11 myscript.pl
```

Comment: I think on windows you need [berrybrew](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew) and not perlbrew

Comment: @Håkon Hægland Fixed

Comment: But Am using Active perl

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special. [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) is the de-facto standard version of Perl for Windows, and its installer gives you the option of specifying to which directory you want to install it.

For example, I have

```
...
C:\progs\sp5280-x64   # Perl 5.28, 64-bit
C:\progs\sp5300-x64   # Perl 5.30, 64-bit
C:\progs\sp5302-x64   # Perl 5.32, 64-bit
```

Simply specify which Perl you want to use when you launch a program.

```
C:\progs\sp5302-x64\perl\bin\perl a.pl
```

By editing your PATH and the file association for `.pl` files, you can set the default `perl` used from the console and by double-clicking a `.pl` file.

Answer (score -1):

I suck at Windows administration, but here goes my stupid suggestion anyway.

1)Install different versions of perl in different folders.

2)Include all folders in the %PATH% variable.

3)Rename the perl executables to its version:

```
perl.exe (5.4) --> perl5_4.exe
perl.exe (5.6) --> perl5_6.exe
```

4)When using the console to execute it, use

```
perl5_4 [file]
```

My honest recommendations are:

1. Use VirtualBox or any OS virtualization application, which is heavy in hardware requirements but works like wonders.
2. For any multi-version environment, always use Docker.
3. Just use Linux and install [perlbrew](https://blog.geekuni.com/2015/05/how-to-install-different-versions-of-perl.html)

Comment: How to Include all folders in the %PATH% variable? DO you mean set a environment variable?

Comment: [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Simple Way to Do this use Virtual machine
and insall os in VIRTUAL BOX and Install old/new Version in Virtual machine.
[Download Virtual BOx](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: Thank You. Is it possible without using VIRTUAL BOX?